# retrieve gmail using telnet

Tags: gmail, telnet

How do I see the mails in my gmail inbox using telnet? I typed telnet pop.gmail.com 995 at the command prompt and it shows me a blank screen. No message confirming whether it is connected and after a few seconds, it goes back to the command prompt. What's happening ?

Answer (score 4):

Port `995/tcp` is for POP3S which means POP3 over SSL. Since `telnet` is no SSL client and you don't "speak" SSL, you won't get an answer that way.

Either you use `110/tcp` and POP3 (which is unencrypted) with `telnet` or you try it with OpenSSL:

```
openssl s_client -connect pop.gmail.com:995
```